# List all files in a directory with abosolute paths (excluding directories)

Tags: linux, path, directory, grep, pwd

I've currently got:

```
ls -1 $(pwd)/*
```

Gives me all the files in a directory with absolute paths - but formats it with the directory at the start of each list of files.

Is there a way just to get a list of files in a directory recursively (absolute paths) - excluding the directory/sub-directories themselves?

Comment: Sounds like you were describing ls -1R $(pwd)/*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find $(pwd) -type f -print
```

or

```
find $(pwd) -type f -ls
```

Comment: If one has files with spaces you'll need to edit the result of this command - space -> _.

Answer (score 0):

If you are feeding it into something else, you might want -print0 (to handle filenames with spaces).

E.g.: find . -type f -print0 | xargs --null --no-run-if-empty grep